# jquery prevent form from submitting if fields are empty?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using the following code to try and change the border colour of my input boxes and prevent the form submitting if the fields are empty.

Whilst this changes the border colours, the form still submits, can someone please show me where I am going wrong here, thanks in advance

```
<div class="home_column">
    <div class="login_form">
        <form name="login" id="login" action="include/validate_login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
            <h21>Username</h21><br/>
            <input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername"><br/>

            <h21>Password</h21><br/>
            <input type="password" class="login_form_front" autocomplete="off"  id="mypassword" name="mypassword"><br/>

            <input type="submit" class="buttons_login" value="Login" id="login" name="login">
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["login"]["myusername"].value;
    var b = document.forms["login"]["mypassword"].value;
    if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "") {
        if (a == null || a == "") { 
            document.forms["login"]["myusername"].style.borderColor = "#963634"; 
        }
        if (b == null || b == "") { 
            document.forms["login"]["mypassword"].style.borderColor = "#963634"; 
        }

        $(".form_error").show();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180 
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use plugins to validate your form easily  http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: Why not try out jquery validate plugin?

Comment: jQuery validate is a little overkill for two inputs in one form.

Comment: I think you should also use e.preventDefault() to stop the form from executing its usual submit event ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Thanks for the suggestion but I don't really want to use plugins.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ Did u try this option? Will make it easier using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error on this line:

```
scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180
```

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined*
and that's because the form_error does not exist on the html code you provided.

which make the code break and through an error before the `return false` line.
Everything else is ok

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object to event handler and use event.preventDefault instead of return false;

```
onsubmit="validateForm(event);"> 

function validateForm(event) {
  // your code
   if(conditionToStopSubmit) 
       event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an odd mix of jQuery and plain JS code. Try this, attaching the event to the form submission in jQuery and using `preventDefault` to stop the request being made if the inputs are empty:

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="include/validate_login.php" method="post">
    <!-- your HTML -->
</form>
```

```js
$('#login').submit(function(e) {
    var formValid = true;
    var $username = $('#myusername');
    var $password = $('#mypassword');

    if ($username.val() == '') {
       formValid = false;
       $username.css('border-color', '#963634');
    }
    if ($password.val() == '') {
       formValid = false;
       $password.css('border-color', '#963634');
    }

    if (!formValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".form_error").show();
        $(document).animate({
            scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180 
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try add **required** in input text

example

`<input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername" required>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, why not do everything in jQuery? Check out my dirty version below:

```
(function($) {

  $("#login").on("submit", validate);

  function validate(e) {
    var $form = $("#login"),
        $uname = $form.find("input[name='myusername']"), // or $form.find("input.login_form_front") or $form.find("#myusername")
        $pwd   = $form.find("input[name='mypassword']"),
        unameVal = $.trim($uname.val()) || "", // default ""
        pwdVal = $pwd.val() || "", // no trimming as pwd could be spaces
        isValid = true;
    if (!unameVal) {
        $uname.css({ borderColor: 'red' });
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!pwdVal.length) {
        $pwd.css({ borderColor: 'red' });
         isValid = false;
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Live demo: [Validate form submit](http://jsfiddle.net/nxkddfjo/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="home_column">
<div class="login_form">
<form name="login" id="login" action="include/validate_login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
<h21>Username</h21><br/>
<input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername" required><br/>
<h21>Password</h21><br/>
<input type="password" class="login_form_front" autocomplete="off"  id="mypassword" name="mypassword" required>
<br/>
<input type="submit" class="buttons_login" value="Login" id="login" name="login">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

try this code, And make sure that your browser is up to date.

Here I have just added a keyword "required" that is enough.